# What are the steps for deploying a Meteor app to Galaxy?

Tags: javascript, meteor, modulus.io

Production and development apps currently deployed to Modulus need to be deployed to Galaxy, and CNAMES cut over.
What is the correct sequence of steps to do this without disturbing existing users?
What are the steps relevant to binary NPM packages, SSL/CNAMES?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did for deploying to galaxy.

1. File a zendesk support ticket to whitelist your domain name.
2. Head over to your domain manager(godaddy or google) and add a CNAME record to with `(Name: www, Type: CNAME, TTL: xhr, data: galaxy-ingress.meteor.com)`
3. Then follow the galaxy help docs, its straight forward:
   https://galaxy.meteor.com/help/deploying-to-galaxy
   PS: galaxy does not allow root domain deploying. `Ex domainname.com`
   It has to be `www.domainname.com`